# Need for speed(ier sql query)

Tags: sql-server

Running this query takes 30-40 seconds and I need to make it faster. Any help is appreciated. Update with view script below. It's running on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 in a .NET environment.  It takes 3 or 4 seconds on a smaller db but the db I'm working with is much larger and it's right at the sql time out boundary.

```
WITH TEMP As
     (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT lease_number                                 AS 'lease_number',
                        facility                                     AS 'facility',
                        Lease_Name                                   AS 'Lease_Name',
                        lease_start_date                             AS 'lease_start_date',
                        lease_end_date                               AS 'lease_end_date',
                        slschedule_id                                AS 'slschedule_id',
                        type_id                                      AS 'type_id',
                        lease_id                                     AS 'lease_id',
                        property_id                                  AS 'property_id',
                        VW_FND_LA_PORT_SL.row_id                     AS 'row_id',
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VW_FND_LA_PORT_SL.row_id ASC) ROW_NBR
                 FROM   VW_FND_LA_PORT_SL
                 WHERE  ( classfication = 1
                          AND slschedule_id = 1
                          AND is_dirty = 0
                          AND is_new = 1 )) AS ROWNUM_APPENDED),

     countfinder AS (SELECT Count(*) AS [rowcount]  FROM   TEMP)

SELECT *,
       (SELECT [rowcount] FROM   countfinder) [totalrowcount]
FROM   TEMP
WHERE  ROW_NBR >= ( 1 - ( 1 - 1 )%10 )
  AND  ROW_NBR < ( 1 - ( 1 - 1 )%10 + 10 )
```

Here's the View:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_FND_LA_PORT_SL]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT( L.lease_id ), 
               L.lease_number, 
               L.name AS Lease_Name, 
               L.lease_start_date, 
               L.lease_end_date, 
               F.name AS facility, 
               L.row_id, 
               L.property_id, 
               L.heldby_id, 
               EC.slschedule_id, 
               S.type_id, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN dbo.Udf_isleaseoperational(L.lease_id) = '1' THEN 1 
                 ELSE 2 
               END    AS classfication, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN (SELECT dirty_flag 
                       FROM   la_tbl_slschedule_calc_detail AS D 
                       WHERE  D.lease_id = L.lease_id 
                              AND D.slschedule_id = S.slschedule_id 
                              AND isdeleted = 0) = 1 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END    AS is_dirty, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN ( CASE 
                          WHEN dbo.Udf_isleaseoperational(L.lease_id) = '1' THEN 
                          (SELECT Count(*) 
                           FROM 
                        la_tbl_slschedule_calculation AS O 
                          WHERE 
                          O.lease_id = L.lease_id 
                          AND O.slschedule_id = S.slschedule_id 
                          AND isdeleted = 0) 
                          ELSE (SELECT Count(*) 
                                FROM   la_tbl_slcapitalschedule_calc AS C 
                                WHERE  C.lease_id = L.lease_id 
                                       AND C.slschedule_id = S.slschedule_id 
                                       AND isdeleted = 0) 
                        END ) > 0 THEN 0 
                 ELSE 1 
               END    AS is_new 
FROM   dbo.la_tbl_lease AS L 
       INNER JOIN dbo.vw_fnd_tlu_facility AS F 
               ON L.property_id = F.facilitypk 
       INNER JOIN la_tbl_expense AS E 
               ON L.lease_id = E.lease_id 
       INNER JOIN la_tbl_slschedule_expcategory AS EC 
               ON E.expense_category_id = EC.expense_category_id 
       INNER JOIN la_tbl_slschedule AS S 
               ON S.slschedule_id = EC.slschedule_id 
       INNER JOIN la_tlu_held_by AS H 
               ON L.heldby_id = H.heldby_id 
WHERE  L.isdeleted = 0 
       AND E.isdeleted = 0 
       AND EC.isdeleted = 0 
       AND S.isdeleted = 0 
       AND ( dbo.Udf_getnumberofleaseterms(L.lease_id) > 0 ) 
       AND H.system_type <> '3' 

GO
```

Comment: What does the estimated execution plan look like?

Comment: Is `VW_FND_LA_PORT_SL` a view? If so what is the definition of that?

Comment: Try using s subquery instead of a CTE.

Comment: yes this is a view. Here's what the view looks like:

Comment: I see that view references another view and that the columns in the original query that you are filtering on (`is_new`, `is_dirty`) are calculated columns. Try rewriting the whole thing from scratch against the base tables not views and filtering directly against the base table columns.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing an execution plan or what's going on with VW_FND_LA_PORT_SL (which looks suspiciously like a view)...
This bit:

```
WHERE  ROW_NBR >= ( 1 - ( 1 - 1 )%10 )
       AND ROW_NBR < ( 1 - ( 1 - 1 )%10 + 10 )
```

Is effectively:

```
TOP 10
...
ORDER BY 
    VW_FND_LA_PORT_SL.row_id ASC
```

And the subselect for total rows could be:

```
COUNT(*) OVER() AS [rowcount] -- tsk tsk, using a reserved word for a column name ;)
```

So it looks like you might be confusing the optimizer.  Maybe try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            lease_number AS 'lease_number'
            , facility AS 'facility'
            , Lease_Name AS 'Lease_Name'
            , lease_start_date AS 'lease_start_date'
            , lease_end_date AS 'lease_end_date'
            , slschedule_id AS 'slschedule_id'
            , type_id AS 'type_id'
            , lease_id AS 'lease_id'
            , property_id AS 'property_id'
            , VW_FND_LA_PORT_SL.row_id AS 'row_id'
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY VW_FND_LA_PORT_SL.row_id ASC ) ROW_NBR
            , COUNT(*) OVER() [rowcount]
        FROM
            VW_FND_LA_PORT_SL
        WHERE
            (
                classfication = 1
                AND slschedule_id = 1
                AND is_dirty = 0
                AND is_new = 1
            )
    ) x
WHERE ROW_NBR BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

It *might* save you a pass or two over the set.  It depends on how much obfuscation the optimizer worked out on its own.  Of course, all your time could be spent on that view.  Can't really say w/o an execution plan.  I'm using BETWEEN rather than TOP 10 in case some of the 1's in the original where clause are placeholders for more relevant parameters.